# Get value from SQLite database:

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a Java program in which I use a SQLite database.  I need to get the value stored in a specific column and row, and then convert it to a string.

Can someone please give me a very simple and general way of doing this? I imagine it to be something like "get Name where ID=4".

Comment: There are hundreds of tutorials around the web.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Comment: You shouldn't ask for a ready code, but should do for the tutorial.

Comment: `something like "get Name where ID=4"` **Nearly**: `"SELECT Name FROM Names WHERE id = 4"`. Names is (obviously) the name of the table containing your names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get value or multiple values you need a cursor, see the following function (that return the first value it's perfect to get id's, for example):

```
public String getSingular_Value_InTransaction(String query){
    //Declaration of variables
    Cursor a1 = null;

    try{
        a1 = database.rawQuery(query,null);
        a1.moveToFirst();

        if(a1.getString(0) != null){
            String result = a1.getString(0);
            a1.close();
            return result;
        }
        else{
            a1.close();
            return "";
        }
    }
    catch (NullPointerException ex){
        return "";
    }
    catch (CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException ex){
        return "";
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        Log.e("-- BDD.execute_SelectCommand --","Exception", ex);
        return "";
    }
}
```

Tell me if I helped you and good programming!

Answer (score 0):

use this method ,I guess it will be helpful...

```
public ArrayList<DbHelper> selectData() {
         try {
            Integer subCategoryArray[][] = null;    
             SQLiteDatabase db;
             db = this.getReadableDatabase(); // Read Data
                ArrayList<DbHelper> ar = new ArrayList<DbHelper>(); 
             String strSQL = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
             Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(strSQL, null);

                if(cursor != null)
                {
                    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        subCategoryArray = new Integer[cursor.getCount()][cursor.getColumnCount()];

                        int j= 0;
                        do {                
                            subCategoryArray[j][0] = cursor.getInt(0);
                            subCategoryArray[j][1] = cursor.getInt(1);
                            subCategoryArray[j][2] = cursor.getInt(2);
                            subCategoryArray[j][3] = cursor.getInt(3);
                            subCategoryArray[j][4] = cursor.getInt(4);
                            subCategoryArray[j][5] = cursor.getInt(5);
                            subCategoryArray[j][6] = cursor.getInt(6);
                            subCategoryArray[j][7] = cursor.getInt(7);
                            subCategoryArray[j][8] = cursor.getInt(8);
                            subCategoryArray[j][9] = cursor.getInt(9);
                            subCategoryArray[j][10] = cursor.getInt(10);
                            subCategoryArray[j][11] = cursor.getInt(11);
                            subCategoryArray[j][12] = cursor.getInt(12);


                            DbHelper v= new DbHelper(subCategoryArray[j][0],subCategoryArray[j][1],subCategoryArray[j][2],subCategoryArray[j][3],subCategoryArray[j][4],subCategoryArray[j][5],subCategoryArray[j][6],subCategoryArray[j][7],subCategoryArray[j][8],subCategoryArray[j][9],subCategoryArray[j][10],subCategoryArray[j][11],subCategoryArray[j][12]);
                            ar.add(v);
                            j++;
                        } while (cursor.moveToNext());                      

                    }
                }
                cursor.close();

                return ar;

         } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
         }

    }
```